# Go through one string and print each letter of the name one at a time (using C)

Tags: c

I just want to go through the name and print each letter of the name one at a time. It'ss giving me this error:

`Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print(char **string){
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(*string));
    printf("%s\n", *string);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(*string); i++){
        printf("%d", i);
        printf("%c\n", *string[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    char string[100];
    fgets(string,100,stdin);
    char *useles = strtok(string, " ");
    char *name = strtok(NULL, " ");

    name = strtok(name, "\n");

    print(&name);
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
0j
1o
```

After this output, occurs this error Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV).

I made the code just to run this input: `ola joao`.

The output I expect is:

```
0j
1o
2a
3o
```

I'd like to know what can I do so this works properly.

Comment: Why `char**` as your argument there? That seems excessive.

Comment: Maybe you want `printf("%c\n", (*string)[i]);` instead of `printf("%c\n", *string[i]);`

Comment: @Joao Figueiras, Do you want to print `(*string)[i]` or `*(string[i])`?

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Looks like some homework assignment, and you clearly need to learn a lot about programming in C. Don't overdo it with pointers. Just past `char*` to your function to pass the string. What's the idea behind `strtok(NULL, " ");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program segfaults because `*string[i]` means the first character of the `i`th string of an array of string pointers:

```
printf("%c\n", *string[i]);
```

but you pass the address of a single string pointer.  Instead use you want the first string pointer's `i`th character:

```
printf("%c\n", (*string)[i]);
```

Or even better change your your code to use a regular string.  I made the argument `const` for good measure.  Use symbolic constants instead of repeating magic numbers.  Instead of calculating `strlen(string)` `n+1` times as part of the loop; use the the common C idiom that strings end with `'\0'` (which is false) to terminate the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 100

void print(const char *string){
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(string));
    printf("%s\n", string);
    for (size_t i = 0; string[i]; i++){
        printf("%d", i);
        printf("%c\n", string[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char string[STR_LEN];
    fgets(string, STR_LEN, stdin);
    char *useles = strtok(string, " ");
    char *name = strtok(NULL, " ");
    name = strtok(name, "\n");
    print(name);
}
```